# cromwell fails to download url input file

Tags: wdl

I have an input file that is a URL. Cromwell (v84) fails to pull it when I'm not using "Local" as a backend.  The only difference between a working case and failed case is the name of the backend in the cromwell config.

For example,

this works

```
default = "Local"
  providers
  {
    Local
```

And this fails

```
default = "MyLocal"
  providers
  {
    MyLocal
```

**Command to reproduce error**

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED"

java -Dconfig.file=cromwell_docker.conf \
-Dbackend.providers.MyLocal.config.dockerRoot=$(pwd)/cromwell-executions \
-Dbackend.providers.MyLocal.config.root=$(pwd)/cromwell-executions \
-jar ~/cromwell/cromwell-84.jar run fq_count.wdl -i fq_count.json
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not build the path "https://portal.nersc.gov/cfs/m342/jaws/test_data/sample.fastq". It may refer to a filesystem not supported by this instance of Cromwell. Supported filesystems are: MacOSXFileSystem. Failures:
```

**WDL file**

```
version 1.0
workflow fq_count {
    input {
        File fastq_file
    }
    call count_reads {
      input: fastq = fastq_file
    }
}

task count_reads {
  input {
    File fastq
  }

  command <<<
    ls ~{fastq}
  >>>

  runtime {
    docker: "ubuntu:latest"
  }
}
```

**json**

```
{
  "fq_count.fastq_file": "https://portal.nersc.gov/cfs/m342/jaws/test_data/sample.fastq"
}
```

**Cromwell conf**

```
include required(classpath("application"))

webservice
{
  port = 50110
}

workflow-options
{
  workflow-log-dir: "cromwell-workflow-logs"
  workflow-log-temporary: false
}

call-caching
{
  enabled = true
  invalidate-bad-cache-result = true
}

backend
{
  default = "MyLocal"

  providers
  {

    MyLocal
    {
      actor-factory = "cromwell.backend.impl.sfs.config.ConfigBackendLifecycleActorFactory"

      config
      {

        concurrent-job-limit = 5
        run-in-background = true

        # The list of possible runtime custom attributes.
        runtime-attributes = """
          String? docker
          String? docker_user
        """

        # Submit string when there is no "docker" runtime attribute.
        submit = "/usr/bin/env bash ${script}"

        # Submit string when there is a "docker" runtime attribute.
        submit-docker = "docker run --volume=${cwd}:${docker_cwd} ${docker} /usr/bin/env bash ${script}"

        root = "/cromwell-executions"
        dockerRoot = "/cromwell-executions"

        filesystems
        {
          local
          {
            localization: [ "soft-link", "hard-link", "copy" ]
            http { enabled: true }

            caching {
                duplication-strategy: [ "soft-link", "hard-link", "copy" ]
                hashing-strategy: "xxh64"
            }
          }
        }

        default-runtime-attributes
        {
          failOnStderr: false
          continueOnReturnCode: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```